# How to Fix ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django

i wrote this code :

```
from .forms import *
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form= TaskForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    context= {'tasks':tasks , 'form':form}
    return  render(request, 'tasks/list.html' , context)
```

and after running it it gave me this error :
**
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks.forms'
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting this error one of the reasons could be that the file which you are calling could have some spelling problems such as:
you could write forms ==> froms so in this cases if you import the module in another module with form spelling could lead you to an error called ModuleNotFoundError